# I have a trouble when I use Tensorflow to save model. File too large

Tags: tensorflow

```
2018-10-08 07:03:40.303219 Saving checkpoint of model...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train_reconstruction_conv5.py", line 188, in <module>
    save_path = saver.save(sess, checkpoint_name)
  File "/home/fanghb/python35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1645, in save
    meta_graph_filename, strip_default_attrs=strip_default_attrs)
  File "/home/fanghb/python35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1683, in export_meta_graph
    graph_def=ops.get_default_graph().as_graph_def(add_shapes=True),
  File "/home/fanghb/python35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3005, in as_graph_def
    result, _ = self._as_graph_def(from_version, add_shapes)
  File "/home/fanghb/python35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2963, in _as_graph_def
    c_api.TF_GraphToGraphDef(self._c_graph, buf)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Cannot serialize protocol buffer of type tensorflow.GraphDef as the serialized size (2950754208bytes) would be larger than the limit (2147483647 bytes)
```

When I train my model, I raise above exceptions.Moreover, I found my meta file is very large in my checkpoints.

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52266253/meta-graph-file-becomes-too-large-for-tensorflow-to-save

Comment: Thank you . I have sovled it.

Answer (score 2):

tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((features, labels)) embed the features and labels arrays in your TensorFlow graph as tf.constant() operations. 
see more https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/datasets#consuming_numpy_arrays